# React : yarn start err

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "^26.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in 
the tree:

  C:\Users\UNION\node_modules\babel-jest (version: 27.0.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in 
the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:    

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\UNION\node_modules\babel-jest is outside your 
project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in 
your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected 
react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file 
in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want 
to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

- I'm not able to solve this issue, I did tried the following steps but it seems like I'm not getting this? Please give some suggestions, so that i could work on my project smoothly.
- Whenever I tend to run `yarn start` it shows me this error.

Comment: Follow the error suggestions

Comment: try to remove global `babel-jest` by command `yarn -g remove babel-jest`, then repeat steps

Comment: @KickButtowsk Hey, as I said earlier, I tried following those steps however it didn't worked out well.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Thank you, I'll surely try this out :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `node_modules` folder in your user profile directory which shouldn't exist. Maybe you ran `npm install <something>` in your user profile once by accident without `-g`.

Delete `c:\Users\UNION\node_modules` and you should be fine.

---

Note that this was actually in the list of suggestions that you already got:

```
  6. Check if C:\Users\UNION\node_modules\babel-jest is outside your  project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in  your home folder.
```

You wrote you tried the steps - next time it would be great if you could also include the results of these attempts in the question so we know what you tried and what effect it had. In this case, for example "#6: Yes, it is outside of my project directory, but I'm not sure what to do about it".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question!

```
To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in  the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:    

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\UNION\node_modules\babel-jest is outside your  project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in  your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected  react-scripts) installed babel-jest.
```